# C++ saving records to file

Tags: c++

i've been thinking how to do this "save to file" thing all night, but it seems that luck wasnt on my side.. .
I am new to this, and i want to get learned, thats all.
I am from Bulgaria, and for those who wonder what is "edinen", this is your citizen number as a member of that country. (I still dont know how to explain this...)

Here is what I've got
(I've already included the "fstream", but i still dont know how to use it!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
#define n 30 
int num=0;
struct uslugi
{
    char name[30];
    char surname[30];
    char lastname[30];
    char illness[30];
    long int edinen;
}grupa[n];
void add_record();
void show_record();
void search_record();
void remove_record();
void add_record() // FUNCTION - ADD RECORD(S)
{
    system("title Add Record");
    int br;
    cout<<"\n How many pacients do you want to enter?";
    cout<<"\n >> ";
    cin>>br;
    for(int i=num;i<num+br;i++)
    {
        cout<<"\n \t\t   ENTERING DATA FOR PACIENT NUMBER - "<<i+1<<endl;
        cout<<"\n Name:";
        cout<<"\n >> ";
        cin>>grupa[i].Name;
        cout<<"\n Surname:";
        cout<<"\n >> ";
        cin>>grupa[i].surname;
        cout<<"\n Lastname:";
        cout<<"\n >> ";
        cin>>grupa[i].lastname;
        cout<<"\n edinen:";
        cout<<"\n >> ";
        cin>>grupa[i].edinen;
        cout<<"\n Ill from:";
        cout<<"\n >> ";
        cin>>grupa[i].illness;
    }
    num=num+br;
}
void show_record() // FUNCTION - SHOW RECORD(S)
{
    if (num==0)
    {
        cout<<"\t\t  by far there are no pacient at all \n";

    }
    cout<<"\n \t\t\t list with all pacients"<<num<<endl;
    for(int i=0;i<num;i++)
    {
    cout<<"\n Name:";
    cout<<"\n >> "<<grupa[i].name;
    cout<<"\n Surname:";
    cout<<"\n >> "<<grupa[i].surname;
    cout<<"\n Lastname:";
    cout<<"\n >> "<<grupa[i].lastname;
    cout<<"\n edinen:";
    cout<<"\n >> "<<grupa[i].edinen;
    cout<<"\n Ill from:";
    cout<<"\n >> "<<grupa[i].illness;
    cout<<"\n\n";

    }
}
void remove_record() // FUNCTION - DELETE RECORD(S)
{
    int k,index;
    for(int i=0;i<num;i++)
    {
    cout<<"\n("<<i+1<<") "<<endl;
    cout<<"Pacient name: "<<grupa[i].name<<endl;
    cout<<"Surname: "<<grupa[i].surname<<endl;
    cout<<"Lastname: "<<grupa[i].lastname<<endl;
    cout<<"edinen: "<<grupa[i].edinen<<endl;
    cout<<"Ill from: "<<grupa[i].illness<<endl<<endl;
    }
    cout<<"Who do you want to delete? \n >> ";
    cin>>index;
    for(k=0;k<num;k++)
    {
        if(k>=index)
        {
            grupa[k].edinen=grupa[k+1].edinen;
        }
        if(k==num-1)
            break;
        else
            cout<<"BY FAR THERE IS NO DATA HERE"<<endl;
    }
    num--;

        for (i=0;i<num;i++)
    {
    cout<<"Pacient name: "<<grupa[i].name<<endl;
    cout<<"Surname: "<<grupa[i].surname<<endl;
    cout<<"Lastname: "<<grupa[i].lastname<<endl;
    cout<<"edinen: "<<grupa[i].edinen<<endl;
    cout<<"Ill from: "<<grupa[i].illness<<endl<<endl;
    }
}
void print_count() // FUNCTION - PRINTING
{
    cout<<"\n \t\t\t NUMBER OF PACIENTS - "<<num<<endl;
    cout<<""<<endl;
}


void search_record() // FUNCTION - SEARCHING
{
    int flag=0;
    long int tempegn;
    cout<<"\n Type the edinen for the pacient you search: ";
    cout<<"\n >> ";
    cin>>tempegn;
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
        if(tempegn==grupa[i].edinen)
        {
    cout<<"Pacient name: "<<grupa[i].name<<endl;
    cout<<"Surname: "<<grupa[i].surname<<endl;
    cout<<"Lastname: "<<grupa[i].lastname<<endl;
    cout<<"edinen: "<<grupa[i].edinen<<endl;
    cout<<"Ill from: "<<grupa[i].illness<<endl<<endl;
            flag++;
        }
        if (!flag)
        {
            cout<<"\n\t PACIENT WITH THAT NAME DOESNT EXCIST \n\n";
        }
}

void main() // MAIN FUNCTION (MENU)
{
    int choice;
    do
    {
        cout<<"\n\t\t*******************   Menu   *******************"<<endl;
        cout<<"\t\t*                                              *";
        cout<<"\n\t\t*          1.Add new pacient                   *";
        cout<<"\n\t\t*          2.Search for a pacient by edinen    *";
        cout<<"\n\t\t*          3.Delete pacient                    *";
        cout<<"\n\t\t*          4.List with all pacients            *";
        cout<<"\n\t\t*          5.Exit                             *";
        cout<<"\n\t\t*                                              *\n";
        cout<<"\t\t************************************************"<<endl;
        cout<<"\n Type your choice!  ";
        cout<<"\n >> ";
        cin>>choice;
        switch(choice)
        {
        case 1:{print_count();add_record();break;}
        case 2:{print_count();search_record();break;}
        case 3:{print_count();remove_record();break;}
        case 4:{print_count();show_record();}
        }
    }
    while(choice!=5);
}
```

Comment: That you're asking about your using the `fstream` family is ironic, since using the `iostream` library for input/output is about the only thing this code does that in any way pins it as requiring C++ at all.

Comment: In the `add_record` function you have a possible buffer-overflow situation. What is `num + br` is larger than `n`? Then you would write beyond what's allocated for `grupa`.

Comment: Where are you even trying to use file io in your code?

Comment: I have one question: I really did not understand why in every tutorial over i have to start my funcktion with "int" ?

Comment: The first `for` loop in your `remove_record` function should just loop up to `i < num-1`, so you can remove that broken `if (i == num-1) break; else cout << ".."` bit, as that `cout << ".."` bit will fire on every iteration.

Comment: I don't see where you're trying to do file I/O in this program.  It seems self contained—the only way to get data in is through a human entering it, and there's no menu option for saving or loading.

Comment: Joe Z, this makes -1 records to show in "delete" function

Comment: This is what I am asking for, an explanation of how to do this.

Comment: I will try by this

``#include <iostream>

#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    ofstream log("output.log");
    ostream placeHolder = cout;
    cout = log;
    cout << "this is a test..." << endl; // note that the endl is a little more important here since it will flush the buffer.
    log.close();
    cout = placeHolder;
    cout << "this is also a test..." << endl;
    return 0;
}
`` 
and then type... stupid me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you read a book, or at least some documentation about this. Also, to understand how this kind of input works, it is required knowledge of oop concepts. As far as I noticed you do not have such a knowledge, I would suggest you stick for a while with procedural i/o functions from C, like fprintf. A google search will show many resources about them and they are pretty easy to understand, at least compared with those from C++, like the ones you are using.

To answer to your question, I will try to explain how to achive what you want. Note that this is a very simplified explanation and not 100% accurate.

Firstly, you need to open the file and create a i/o stream, using `ifstream` for input files or `ofstrsam` for output files:

ifstream f("input_filename");

ofstream g("output_filename);

After you created f and/or g (they are not both requied. Also, f and g are just random names) you can use them in the same way you use cin and cout, in this case, as f is for input, it should be used like cin.

Comment: Well this `` After you created f and/or g (they are not both requied. Also, f and g are just random names) you can use them in the same way you use cin and cout, in this case, as f is for input, it should be used like cin.`` is what i've been searching all the time i think. THANK YOU PAUL92
Thanks for all the answers some tried to give me! I assume the problem of not knowing how to do this is really not trying everything, but asking dumb questions! My fault!

Comment: I am glad it helped. Please consider upvoting and/or accepting my answer. This is how one says thanks on stackexchange network.